# creating a superclass object by using subclass' constructor

Tags: subclass, superclass

let's say we have a superclass Person and a subclass Child, I'm ok that
Person a = new Child();
the statement works as Child is a subclass of Person, so it's permitted in java, but I can't stop thinking why and under what circumstances do we need to do this?
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you want to list a list of persons by date of birth, which is a Person property. And vice versa if to group a list of children by school or parent (siblings), which might be a Child only property.

Comment: yea thx mate that make sense